# Integrate NPM build in ANT script

Tags: npm, ant

I have an existing **ANT** file to build java code. I need to integrate the following command in the build:

1) **npm install**

2) **npm run build**

How can I integrate it?

I believe I need to add a new target to run these command but not sure about exact code/xml changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<target name="npm-install">
        <exec dir="./web/public" executable="cmd.exe" output="npm-install.txt">
         <arg line="/c npm install"/>
        </exec>
</target>

<target name="npm-build">
    <exec dir="./web/public" executable="cmd.exe" output="npm-build.txt">
     <arg line="/c npm run build"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: How do we do for Ubuntu machines ?